# Customized Increment Arrows on Input doesn't work! How to collect the input value through buttons?

Tags: html, angular, button, input, angular7

At the beginning of my application, using the input arrows or the keyboard, my data were sent without any problem.
Wanting to make the UI more friendly I decided to hide the browser arrows and implement some buttons to add and subtract in the same input.
I have in my html the following two elements.
One is an input to determine the unit to add to a cart and the other element is a button that should send that info to another component

```
<div class='child'>
  <div class='fourth'>
    <ul class='p-0 m-0'>
      <li *ngFor='let item of product.items' class='def-number'>
        <a onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('input[type=number]').stepDown()" class="minus">-</a>
        <input type='number' placeholder='0' [(ngModel)]='item.quantity' (change)='this.updateCart(item)' min='0'>
        <a onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('input[type=number]').stepUp()" class='plus'>+</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='child d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center'>
  <div class='fifth'>
    <ul class='p-0 m-0'>
      <li *ngFor='let item of product.items' style='line-height: 82px'>
        <button class='cart' (click)='addItem()'><i class='icon-addcart'></i></button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this is my function

```
  updateCart(item, idProduct) {
    console.log(item);
    this.cart.updateItem(item);
    this.eCart.next(this.cart.getCart());
  }
```

If I modify the amount of input with the keyboard I get the data without any problem to my 'updateCart()' function.
the problem comes with 'plus' and 'minus' buttons and the class button 'cart', since I don't know how to make it collect the data in the same way

Someone who can give me an idea of what I should do?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
public updateQuantity(update: number): void {
  this.item.quantity += update;
}

public updateCart(item): void {
    console.log(item);
    this.cart.updateItem(item);
    this.eCart.next(this.cart.getCart());
}
```

```html
<div class='child'>
  <div class='fourth'>
    <ul class='p-0 m-0'>
      <li *ngFor='let item of product.items' class='def-number'>
        <a (click)='updateQuantity(-1)' class="minus">-</a>
        <input type='number' placeholder='0' [(ngModel)]='item.quantity' (ngModelChange)='updateCart(item)' min='0'>
        <a (click)='updateQuantity(1)' class='plus'>+</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='child d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center'>
  <div class='fifth'>
    <ul class='p-0 m-0'>
      <li *ngFor='let item of product.items' style='line-height: 82px'>
        <button class='cart' (click)='addItem()'><i class='icon-addcart'></i></button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can you try (ngModelChange)="updateCart($event)" instead of (change)='updateCart(item)'?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but it doesn't work
                    <input class='quantity' type='number' placeholder='0' [(ngModel)]='item.quantity' (ngModelChange)="updateCart(item)" min='0'>

Comment: Are you sure that onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('input[type=number]').stepDown()"
is working as intended, by default click handlers are used as (click)="callbackFunction()" in Angular.

If that is not the case I would recommend directly changing value.quantity value in ngModel instead of using stepUp and stepDown.

Comment: the input values are changing and I've tried to call the function on the buttons but it doesn't work either

Comment: I have updated my initial answer with the changes I've recommended, can you confirm that it is not working?

Comment: I've tried and tested it on the buttons, they keep changing the value within the input field and but it doesn't do anything in the ts

Comment: I think it is a problem with two way binding, can you try to set the value manually in the ngModelChange callback and change [(ngModel)] to just [ngModel]